# missing credentials in NestJs Passport

Tags: typescript, authentication, jwt, nestjs, passport.js

I've built an NestJS API with authentification.
I'm using NestJS passport and I create a JSON web token when a user logs in.
I've done numerous searches and I really don't know what I'm doing wrong.
I get the error

> missing credentials
> from the API console.

Does anyone has a solution for this issue?

Here is my authentification service:

```js
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { UtilisateurService } from '../utilisateur/utilisateur.service';
import { JwtService } from '@nestjs/jwt';
const bcrypt = require('bcryptjs');
import { jwtConstants } from './constants';

@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
    constructor(private utilisateurService : UtilisateurService, private jwtService: JwtService) {}

    async validateUser(username: string, pass: string): Promise<any> {
        const user = await this.utilisateurService.findOne(username);
        if (user && bcrypt.compareSync(pass, user.password)) {
            const { password, ...result } = user;
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }

    async login(user: any) {
        // const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user.userId };
        const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user._id };
        return {
            access_token: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
        };
    }
}
```

I sent the request like this:

```js
const token = 'eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6IlV0aWxpc2F0ZXVyMSIsInN1YiI6IjYxZjIyZjQzYTBjMWE5M2YxYTVkNDE1MCIsImlhdCI6MTY0NDIxMjM4NSwiZXhwIjoxNjQ0MjE1OTg1fQ.CDItoaUwhrCUs7XAb9vpvfikq8yX7E89nj_luU576MU'

export const config = {
    headers: {
        Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token
    }
} 

mounted() {
        // console.log(VueCookies.get("user-params").access_token)
        axios.get('http://localhost:3000/projet', config)
        .then(response => {
            this.projets = response.data
            // console.log(this.projets)
            this.projetsSearched = this.projets
        })
        .catch(e => {
          console.log(e)
        })
    },
```

And here is my local strategy

```
import { Strategy } from 'passport-local';
import { PassportStrategy } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { Injectable, UnauthorizedException } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';


@Injectable()
export class LocalStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'thejwt') {
    constructor(private authService: AuthService) {
        super();
    }

    async validate(username: string, password: string): Promise<any>{
        const user = await this.authService.validateUser(username,password);
        const user2 = user._doc;
        if(!user2){
            throw new UnauthorizedException();
        
        }
        return user2;
    }
}
```

Comment: *invalid signature* on jwt.io and *missing credentials* are two very different things. The invalid signature is most often caused by wrong usage of jwt.io. Did you paste the secret or public key into the input field in the right column under verify signature? Without a key it's not possible for jwt.io to verify the signature. The missing credentials is unrelated to that. What exactly did you do when you got that error?

Comment: Hello! I did paste the secret key in the right column and it seems that the signature is correct (I'm new with this kind of stuff so my bad on this).
I get a "missing credentials" when i login from my front app and try to access a request wih the Bearer token
It works fine on postman

Comment: How exactly did you send the request with the bearer token from your app?  Please edit the question to add details.

Comment: I did! Don't hesitate to ask me more questions about this issue

Comment: thanks for the reminder and update. `Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token` looks good. I can't see what's wrong. I updated your question, because the part about jwt.io was not a real problem. Keep in mind, updates (edits) of the question raise the chance that someone will see and answer it.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer! 
I'm really confused about this issue, I hope I'll get a life saving answer!
Have a good day

Comment: A little late to the party, but... did you make sure that you really send your body as JSON and not raw or form-data? That happened to me and I'm still banging my head at my desk!